# How to get a buddypress field of current user?

Tags: buddypress

how to get the value of a field of the current connected user in buddyPress ?

ex: How to print out :

```
My gender is : {gender}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current user id: `get_current_user_id()`
Then use `xprofile_get_field_data`

My gender is : `<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data('gender', get_current_user_id(), 'comma'); ?>`

http://hookr.io/functions/xprofile_get_field_data/